# Display UAC shield icon on a ToolStripItem

Tags: .net, winforms, uac, toolstripitem

is there a recommended way (like sending BCM_SETSHIELD to a button control) to display the UAC Shield icon on a ToolStripItem? ToolStripItem is not a control anyway, so i wonder what the best-practise for that is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing [SIID_SHIELD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762542(VS.85).aspx) to [SHGetStockIconInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205(VS.85).aspx) is the documented (native) way to get the UAC shield icon (Vista+)